# Can I change the link back of other website via our htaccess?

Tags: redirect

Scenario:

Third party website has a link going to our homepage. We would like to redirect it to another part of our site, say http://website.com/about-us instead of homepage. Is that possible to be done on our own server? Let's say we don't have contact to this third party website. If yes, can you provide a sample redirection rule?

Also, can you verify if I can follow this example http://dmr.ath.cx/notes/rewrite.html?

Answer (score 1):

Actually, the information the you have linked is very useful to your issue, you can even solve what you want with that link. However, you can still try this *.htaccess* code:

```
Options +FollowSymlinks
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} referrer\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^/?$ /about-us [R]
```

And if the homepage basename that they've linked is *home.php* then just change the code `/?` on the rewrite rule with that basename, just like this:

```
RewriteRule ^home.php$ /about-us [R]
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks!

For the benefit of others, this what worked for us too.

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} ^http://website\.com.*
RewriteRule .* http://%{HTTP_HOST}/index.html
```